# Is it possible for Ansible to reuse the existing SSH connection to the remote host in order to rsync some directories?

Tags: ssh, rsync, ansible

Following script is meant to be copied and run on the remote host, i.e. `192.168.1.142`, `ansible-playbook -u root -i inventory.ini sync-w-ctrl.yml`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

au=jimmy
dirs=(
"/home/${au}/Music"
)

ctr_st="192.168.1.112"

sync_w_ctrl() {
for d in ${dirs[@]}; do 
  rsync -e ssh -av --delete --no-o --no-g --chown=oumaima:oumaima "root@${ctr_st}:${d}" /home/oumaima/Music
done
}

sync_w_ctrl
#apt update

#
```

If it try to copy this script to the hosts (just one host for now, `192.168.1.142`) from my inventory and run it there it does not work. I get the following output:

```
PLAY [Run Bash script on all machines with multiple file arguments] *************************************

TASK [Copy and run a script that syncs directories] *****************************************************
fatal: [192.168.1.142]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 192.168.1.142 closed.", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
192.168.1.142              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The script does run correctly once I comment out the call to `sync_w_ctrl` and uncomment `#apt update`.
The content of the playbook, `sync-w-ctrl.yml` is:

```
- name: Run Bash script on all machines with multiple file arguments
  hosts: myhosts
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    au: "jimmy"
  tasks:
    - name: Copy and run a script that syncs directories
      script: /home/{{ au }}/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/ansible/sync-w-ansible.sh
```

Is it at all doable with ansible, for a remote host to 'reuse' the existing ssh connection in order to rsync some directories?

##### Constraints of the problem:

For security reasons, I cannot have `openssh-server` installed and `sshd` running on my control station. That's why I was hoping to 'reuse' the ssh connection established by `$ctr_st`  to `192.168.1.142` in order to sync directories with rsync.

Comment: I haven't looked into all of this but just looking at the title.. What I think might be possible is for multiple things to be tunneled through an SSH connection  'cos you can e.g.  use -L twice in the command that connects to the server.    I don't know if that idea of mine is  something you already knew about, or has any relevance to what you are doing,